# Stop all forks after signal

Tags: c

I have a program that create two forks to search sequentially a password. The first fork search from the beginning to the middle and the second fork from the middle to the end.

```
void handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("[H] [%d] recibe la señal SIGUSR1\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
}

void handler_padre(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("[P] [%d] recibe la señal SIGUSR1\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main ( int argc, char * argv [ ] )
{

    char * claveCifrada = argv[1] ;
    char * pwd_0 = argv[2] ;
    char * pwd_1 = argv[3] ;        
    int verbose ;       
    int pid, pid_1, pid_2 ;
    char pwdMedio [6] ; 
    int estado ;

    trataSenial.sa_handler = handler_padre ;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &trataSenial, NULL) ;    

    int resultado = analizarArgumentos(argc, argv, &verbose) ;

    if (resultado != 0) return(resultado) ;

    strcpy(pwdMedio, pwd_0) ;

    obtenPwd((valor(pwd_0)+valor(pwd_1))/2, (char *)&pwdMedio) ;     

    printf("pwdMedio = \"%s\"\n\n", pwdMedio) ;
    printf("[P] [%d] iniciado\n", getpid());
                                                /* ver: setsid, kill(0, _) */

    if ((pid_1 = fork()) == 0) {
        signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
        resultado = 
            buscaEImprimeClave(claveCifrada, pwd_0, pwdMedio, 0, getppid()) ;
        return(resultado) ;
    } 
    if ((pid_2 = fork()) == 0) {
        signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
        siguientePassword(pwdMedio) ;       
        resultado = 
            buscaEImprimeClave(claveCifrada, pwdMedio, pwd_1, 0, pid_1) ;
        return(resultado) ; 
    }
    waitpid(pid_1, &estado, 0) ;    
    waitpid(pid_2, &estado, 0) ;
    /*pid = wait((int *)&estado) ;  
    pid = wait((int *)&estado) ;*/

    printf("\n fin del proceso padre\n\n") ;
    return(0) ;
}
```

To send the signal I use:

```
/*
In the first fork, pidOtro == getppid()
In the second fork, pidOtro == pid_1
*/
kill(-pidOtro, SIGUSR1);
```

The program end well, ending both forks, but when executing `time ./program` it can't finish without killing it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
You are missing crucial information from your code; it isn't clear what's going on in the `buscaEImprimeClave()` function.  That makes it hard for us to guess what's going wrong.  You don't need to show us the 'real' functions, but you do need to show us some function that does sufficient to reproduce the problem claimed.  Your question title is also misleading.

Comment: where do you call the `kill` from?